# res.json or res.send inside foreach loop async await function error: [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, foreach, async-await

I have been facing this issue in NodeJs for many days. So I am using an array of Ids that will be matched in mongo documents.
Body Request:

```
{
"applicantIds": 
["62e132596e914ded81846231","62a6c630c7f13211aa0a791a","62d6592bf3db4853b0ba1715"],
"userId":"6299ccdaba5dc977068c0a09"
}
```

I am checking the applicantIds in the loop for their existence in the database using async and await. After that I am submitting the data into another table. sending response back to the developer using res.send()
but it is throwing the error :[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

Here is the code inside for each loop

```
// loop starts
newTestLink.save().then(function (newTestLink) {
  questionIdArr = [];
  var stageEmail = {
    subject: 'Thanks for taking participation',
    // content: JSON.stringify(newTestLink),
    html:
      '<b>Hello, <strong>Candidate</strong>, Your test link is:\n<b>' +
      test_url +
      '</b></p>',
  };
  if (
    !helper.send_email(applicantEmailId, stageEmail.subject, stageEmail.html)
  ) {
    return res.status(500).send({
      message: 'Something went wrong.',
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(200).send({
      message: 'link has been sent.',
    });
  }
});
// Loop ends
```

how can I send the response back to the postman as I know the issue is whether Response is being called twice or thrice?
Note: as it is an async and await function if I write Res.send() outside the loop. It prints the response before running the whole function.

Comment: Can you post the whole function code?

Comment: Create an array of promises wait for the response then send your response.
Do not do async requests in a loop if they are not dependent on each other.

Comment: @Ethanolle the requests are dependent on each other. so that need to use Async.

Comment: @lpizzinidev
pls send me your email i ll send the whole function